# How do browsers handle HTTP keepalive race condition?

Tags: http, browser, race-condition, keep-alive

There exists a known race condition in the HTTP keepalive mechanism:

- [HTTP KeepAlive connection closed by server but client had sent a request in the mean time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686828/http-keepalive-connection-closed-by-server-but-client-had-sent-a-request-in-the)
- https://github.com/mikem23/keepalive-race

As I understand, I need my HTTP client either to have a shorter timeout than my HTTP server, or retry when getting TCP-FIN or TCP-RST.

My question is, how do today's web-browsers, that [use the HTTP keepalive feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection#Use_in_web_browsers), handle this race condition. Do they retry?

I'll be happy for references, a google search hasn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According the the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.7), in these cases, a server should respond with a 408 error code, signalling to the client that the connection has already been closed on its side. As the RFC states:

> If the client has an outstanding request in transit, the client MAY
> repeat that request on a new connection.

This means that it's up to the client (aka each browser) to decide how a 408 response will be handled. There are 2 alternatives:

- handle it gracefully: retrying the remaining requests in a new connection automatically, so that the user stays completely unaware of the underlying failure that happened
- fail-fast: showing the user a failure with the appropriate 408 error message

For example, it seems that Chrome in the past was following the second approach until a point, where people started considering this as a "buggy" behaviour and switched to the first one. You can find the bug thread related to the Chromium bug [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=377581) and the associated code change [here](https://codereview.chromium.org/303443011).

Note: As you can read in the final emails in the linked thread, Chrome performs these retries, only when some requests have succeeded in this connection. As a result, if you try to reproduce that with a single request, returning a 408 response, you'll notice that Chrome won't probably retry in that case.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and researching this.

Comment: 408 response code is for request timeout - the scenario when a client has started sending the request and is not sending it fast enough.
In Keepalive race, the server closes the connection when a connection has been idle for a while and there are no in-flight requests which the server can see so it cannot send a 408 response to the client.

Comment: @avmohan I don't think that's correct. A server will respond with a 408, even when the client has opened the connection and sent no packet at all. For instance, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/408

Comment: Thanks for the reference, Dimos. I had no idea that there could be a response without a request. Good to know. 
I've seen these race conditions between Apache httpd as a reverse proxy and tomcat.   Tomcat closes a persistent connection (without sending a 408) and at the same time httpd forwards a request from client resulting in a 502 error to the client. The only way we could fix these was to keep the idle timeout on httpd lower than tomcat.